# Why is setBackgroundColor() failing only with my custom theme?

Tags: java, android, styles, themes

I thought I successfully created a striped Android ListView, in which the background colors of the list items alternate.  It works perfectly when I use Theme.Holo.Light as my application's theme (, in the Manifest.)
However, when I defined a custom theme for my app, with a custom background color, the stripes disappeared, replaced by the single background color defined in my theme.  **Why is it that my custom theme's background color cannot be overridden by setBackgroundColor() in getView()? How can I fix this issue?**  Thanks!

UPDATE: I've realized that the application background is being rendered in front of my View's backgrounds!  (Also, in front of a ProgressBar in my layout, completely obscuring it.)  If I set @color/background_color to be completely transparent, the striping shows through.  So, the question is then, **why is my theme's background rendering in front of some views/backgrounds?**

Theme:

```
<style name="Basic">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_color</item>
</style>
```

getView():

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout itemView;
        Resources res = getResources();
        int[] colors = new int[] {res.getColor(R.color.list_stripe_1),res.getColor(R.color.list_stripe_2)};
        if (convertView == null){
            itemView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater viewInflater;
            viewInflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
            viewInflater.inflate(resource, itemView, true);
        } else {
            itemView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }

        ////Omitting code for populating TextViews..

        itemView.setBackgroundColor(colors[position%colors.length]);
        return itemView;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using setting android:background in the theme, set android:windowBackground. I have not fully investigated why it was impossible to override the theme-set background with setBackgroundColor(), or why using android:background caused the spinner to be obscured, but using windowBackground instead solved the problem.